# Two threads one uses stream Api and other thread CreateFile fails with error ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, win32-process

In my current work, we have several threads running simultaneously,
Through one of the thread we have open a file:

```
std::ofstream fs;    
fs.open(filename.c_str(), std::ofstream::out);
if( fs.is_open() ){
   // do some file operation and write
   fs.close();
}
```

while a separate thread also access the same file:

```
HANDLE handle = CreateFileW(filename.c_str(), GENERIC_READ,0, NULL,OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

it fails and gives error ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION.

I know, we can overcome the issue using synchronisation mechanism,

But can we handle it using file sharing mechanism while opening the file, since one thread is using stream API to open the file, while other uses createFile.

Any input is appreciable.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the reading thread reads at the same time as the writing thread writes?

Comment: The issue is unrelated to your concurrent use. You'd observe the same behavior if everything were implemented on a single thread. Might want to update this question to remove the unrelated information, and produce a [mcve]. That's literally 3 lines of code, including error handling.

Comment: Hi,@user9055801, Did the answer solve your issue? Please feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it if did help.

Answer (score 1):

Your `CreateFile()` call is setting the `dwShareMode` parameter to 0, so it is trying to open the file for *exclusive access*, which will fail if the file is already open.

You need to specify sharing rights that are compatible with how the `ofstream` opens the file, eg:

```c
HANDLE handle = CreateFileW(filename.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```